# How to use set() in python

Tags: python, regex, split

Guys please help me to overcome the issue I've faced while using set() function.
when I run the bellow code the output of the file "iplist.txt" expected to be:

```
192.168.248.2
192.168.248.20
```

but it is as bellow:

```
1
.
4
2
0
9
6
8
```

And, output of print (a) is as bellow:

```
192.168.248.2
192.168.248.2
192.168.248.20
192.168.248.20
```

Here is the code:

```
for key, group in groupby(logfile, key=lambda e: e.split('.',1)[0]):
    for entry in group:
        c.update(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', entry))
    for ip, cnt in c.items():
       if cnt >= 5 and cnt <=10:
          newip.append(ip)
       elif cnt > 10:
          match = re.search(r'->\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})', entry)
          if match:
              a = match.group(1)
              print (a)

          with open("C:\\Users\Raz\\Desktop\\pythondemo\\iplist.txt", 'w+') as f:
              f.write('\n' .join(set(a))+'\n\n')
              f.close()
       else:
           print ("There are no malicious packets yet")
```

Here is the log.txt file containing IPs:

```
12/30-04:09:41.070967 [**] [1:10000001:1] snort alert [1:0000001] [**] [classification ID: 0] [Priority ID: 0] {ICMP} 192.168.232.2:41673 -> 192.168.248.2:21
12/30-04:09:41.070967 [**] [1:10000001:1] snort alert [1:0000001] [**] [classification ID: 0] [Priority ID: 0] {ICMP} 192.168.232.2:41676 -> 192.168.248.2:21
12/30-04:09:41.070967 [**] [1:10000001:1] snort alert [1:0000001] [**] [classification ID: 0] [Priority ID: 0] {ICMP} 192.168.232.2:41673 -> 192.168.248.2:21

12/30-04:09:40.070967 [**] [1:10000001:1] snort alert [1:0000001] [**] [classification ID: 0] [Priority ID: 0] {ICMP} 192.168.232.21:41676 -> 192.168.248.20:21
12/30-04:09:40.070967 [**] [1:10000001:1] snort alert [1:0000001] [**] [classification ID: 0] [Priority ID: 0] {ICMP} 192.168.232.21:41673 -> 192.168.248.20:21
```

Now my question is:

1. why print (a) shows duplicated IPs (not more and not less)?
2. why set(a) extracts unique characters while I want unique IPs

Comment: Your code is wrongly indented and your output does not match the code. Please show the code to your output.

Comment: @Daniel here it is so, because of spacing... but it is right when I run it

Comment: please show the correct code. Indentation is important to understand the problem.

Comment: `print(a)` is executed many times and every time it prints only one IP - it doesn't know other IPs to compare. `set(a)` does `set("192.168.248.2")` because `a` is not list of all IPs but string with single IP. You have to keep all `a` on some list (ie. `all_IP`) and after you leave `for` loop do `set(all_IP)`

Comment: @Daniel I have edited with correct indentation

Comment: @furas exatly. tnx furas

Comment: `Counter` is initialized only once, but evaluated for each group. That does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Daniel it is used in other part of the code that I did not included... jst ignore that

Comment: @RazHamraz: you use the counter to only process IPs with more than 10 occurrences. So this is important for your code, shown here and still is weird.

Answer (score 1):

If the format of you log file remains exactly the same and doesn't changes then you can implement it with pandas as well, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('log.txt' , sep='\s+', header=None)

df[16]=df[16].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[0])
print df[16].unique().tolist()
```

Output:

```
['192.168.248.2', '192.168.248.20']
```

If you don't want to use pandas then wait for other incoming answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is, that `a` is a string:

```
>>> set('192.168.248.20')
set(['.', '1', '0', '2', '4', '6', '9', '8'])
```

your second problem is, that you overwrite your file each time, a new entry is found (mode `'w+'` instead of `'a'`)

The third problem is, that you never collect all IPs to build a set.